# ASP.NET Web API error response and (application/json vs text/json)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

I want to return an error code with the response in my ASP.NET Web Api, so in the controller I do something like this:

```
case ErrorCodes.TimeOut:
{
    HttpError e = new HttpError(fex.Message) { { "ErrorCode", fex.ErrorCode }, { "Tag", fex.Tag } };
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error: e);
}
```

It's ok when I call this api with text/json

```
Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8

{"Message":"Timed out at 8:05 AM","ErrorCode":102,"Tag":"1445933100"}
```

but if I use an empty content-type or application/json (Default settings) I get some standard response like this

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "status": 400,
  "source": "my source",
  "message": "Timed out at 8:05 AM"
}
```

Two questions:

- Best practice for returning an error code (not http code)
- How to configure ASP.NET App to return my custom response.